# Two interfaces as method return type

Tags: vb.net, collections

I'm trying to expose a KeyCollection in my private dictionary to COM so it can support both IEnumerable and ICollection, like ...

```
<ComVisible(True)> _
<InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)> _
Public Interface IEnumerableAndCollection
    Inherits IEnumerable
    Inherits ICollection
End Interface

Public ReadOnly Property Keys() As IEnumerableAndCollection
    Get
        Return pDictionary.Keys
    End Get
End Property
```

KeyCollections *does* implement both IEnumerable and ICollection, but not (obviously) IEnumerableAndCollection. Is there some sort of casting/widening/etc that cover this case? Or can I extend the new interface onto it (tried but failed)?

Comment: `ICollection` is a subclass of `IEnumerable`.  Not sure how this works with COM, but can you just implement and return `ICollection`?

Comment: No, it seems that the methods in Enumerable are hidden when you do this. Very annoying!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have much choice except implementing two properties:

```
Public ReadOnly Property KeysEnumerable() As IEnumerable
  Get
    Return pDictionary.Keys
  End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property KeysCollection() As ICollection
  Get
    Return pDictionary.Keys
  End Get
End Property
```

Or perhaps on the COM side you could have two variables pointing to the same object:

```
Dim keysC As ICollection = GetObject("myexe.exe", "pDictionary.Keys")
Dim keysE As IEnumerable = GetObject("myexe.exe", "pDictionary.Keys")
```

Comment: Bummer. This wouldn't be so much of a problem if KeyCollection had a non-generic version. I could also use Copy into a List, but that's O(n)

Comment: Can you cast the collection as IEnumerable on the COM side? It's been a long time since I have done any COM seriously.

Comment: You can, but then you lose the ICollection... it's frustrating!

Comment: Maybe have two variables on the COM side? I've updated my answer. Sorry if the `GetObject` call is nonsense, I haven't done COM in a long time.